# How to Generate Component-preload.js File for a UI5 Application using SAP Web IDE?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, ui5-tooling

I wanted to know as to how a *Component-preload.js* file can be generated for a UI5 application in SAP Web IDE without using *gulp.js*. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component-preload.js generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061298/component-preload-js-generation)

Answer (score 0):

When using the (old) WebIDE the preload file can get generated, however, I'd suggest to consider switching to the (new) WebIDE Full-Stack. This new WebIDE works with NPM, Grunt etc. When triggering the build the preload files get generated seamlessly.

See my following blogs for some details:

- [Implementing a custom UI5 lib and a UI5 app consuming the lib using
  SAP Full-Stack WebIDE with Grunt](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/03/implementing-a-custom-ui5-lib-and-a-ui5-app-consuming-the-lib-using-sap-full-stack-webide-with-grunt/)
- [The UI5 App Index – a demo using SAP Web IDE Full-Stack to clone a Github repo + build via Grunt](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/18/the-ui5-app-index-a-demo-using-sap-web-ide-full-stack-to-clone-a-github-repo-build-via-grunt/)

You could also have a look at [my example app on github](https://github.com/nzamani/ui5-lib-webide-demo/tree/master/nabi.sample.ui5app) made for the new WebIDE. There you can see the Gruntfile (which is basically the default one generated by the new WebIDE when creating new UI5 projects):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build");

    // good for debugging
    grunt.log.writeln("\n### grunt.config() ###\n" + JSON.stringify(grunt.config(), null, 2));

    grunt.registerTask("default", [
        "clean",
        "lint",
        "build"
    ]);
};
```