# UI5 minifying and uglifying with @ui5/cli

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I'm playing with the UI5 minifying and uglifying. As far as I know, [there are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061970) two common approaches:

1. Grunt task with `gruntfile.cjs`, based on [`grunt-openui5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-openui5).
2. UI5 Tooling with `ui5.yaml`, based on [`@ui5/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui5/cli).

My `ui5.yaml`:

```yaml
specVersion: "2.5"
type: application
metadata:
    name: com.myapp
framework:
    name: OpenUI5
    version: 1.95.0
resources:
    configuration:
        paths:
            webapp: src/webapp
builder:
    cachebuster:
        signatureType: hash
    componentPreload:
        namespaces:
            - "com/myapp"
        paths:
            - "src/webapp"
```

To run the minifying with `@ui5/cli`, I execute the following NPM-Script task: `"test": "ui5 build preload"`, as the result, I get a brand new `dist` folder with minified and debug-friendly files (e.g. `App.controller.js` and `App-dbg.controller.js`), in addition, `Component-preload.js` is generated as well.

My questions:

1. Is Grunt-based approach a legacy, while `@ui5/cli` is standard approach nowadays?
2. Is it possible to get a minified version of the UI5 app (just a `Component-preload.js`) with `@ui5/cli` without a `dist` folder?

Comment: Actually it's a little weird because creating a new library, by default, still uses Grunt, but a new application by default uses ui5 cli

Comment: @Jorg, I assumed, that Grunt is kind of a legacy but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to the [UI5 tooling roadmap](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/506), [`grunt-openui5`](https://github.com/SAP/grunt-openui5/) is targeted to be replaced by the UI5 tooling.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, BTW, there are `@ui5/cli` and `@ui5/builder`, when should I prefer one over another?

Comment: For the consumption of the UI5 tooling, `@ui5/cli` should be installed as intended which [comes with the `@ui5/builder` module](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling#modules). No idea why anyone would choose installing only the sub-modules.

Comment: _why anyone would choose installing only the sub-modules_ — to not install extra, unwanted modules.